# Delegates in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have a list of entities that contains search terms, clicks etc.
The user should be able to compare the amount of clicks between the entities - i.e. all the entities that contains the word "free sample" in the beginning of the search and compare with all the entities that contains the phrase "arrest me" in the end of the phrase.
I can do this with multiple foreach and switch (because the user choose the query and the part of the string) but i understand that by using Linq i can use the "start with" and "end with" functions. could you please guide me through?

Comment: Can you post a bit of code to make it clearer what you have?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ `Where()` to return a set of entities which satisfies a condition:

```
var filtered = entities.Where(e => 
                         e.SearchPattern.StartsWith("Start")
                         &&
                         e.SearchPattern.EndsWith("End"));
```

LINQ `Single()/SingleorDefault()` to return a single entity which satisfies a condition, if more than one found - exception will be thrown.

```
var filtered = entities.Single(e => 
                         e.SearchPattern.StartsWith("Start")
                         &&
                         e.SearchPattern.EndsWith("End"));
```

LINQ `First()`/`Last()` to return first/last entity for the given condition...

```
var filtered = entities.First(e => 
                           e.SearchPattern.StartsWith("Start")
                           &&
                           e.SearchPattern.EndsWith("End"));
```

See [Enumerable class methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) for the full list

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a list of things that start with "free sample" and then another that ends with "arrest me".  Assuming that's what you want, you'll do something like this.

```
// Assumes myStuff is where all of your data is right now
var startsWith = myStuff.Where(x => x.MyString.StartsWith("free sample"));
var endsWith = myStuff.Where(x => x.MyString.EndsWith("arrest me"));

// Now you can do whatever comparisons between the two lists you need
```

Of course, if you just want all of them that start with "free sample" and end with "arrest me" you can just do this

```
var hasBoth = myStuff.Where(x => x.MyString.StartsWith("free sample") && x.MyString.EndsWith("arrest me"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions you mention are just string functions. `s.StartsWith("abc")` and `s.EndsWith("xyz")`. In a LINQ query you can use them in a where clause.

```
var startIndexes = phrases
    .Where(p => p.StartsWith("free sample")
    .Select((p, i) => i);

var endIndexes = phrases
    .Where(p => p.EndsWith("arrest me")
    .Select((p, i) => i);
```

These two queries return the indexes of phrases that start, respectively end with a certain string. I use an overload of select that accepts the index as second parameter.